# frontend search by custom option sku

Tags: custom-options, search, sku

I know out of the box the Magento search allows you to search by product sku. This is working fine on our site. However, if you have a product with a custom option that appends to the sku, searching by the whole sku does not return any results. So, for example, a simple product with the sku of 1234 with custom options set to add -S,-M, or -L depending on the selection, can be found in a frontend search using "1234" but not "1234-M" Is there any way to have the 1234-M return the correct product?

Comment: product with custom option doesn't create new product if you create a configurable product then associated product create with different sku, so when you create associated product that time set visibility "search" so when you search "1234-M" then this product will showing.